ProgressRing is not visible on Button Click using PowerShell
I am building one tool using WPF + PowerShell + MahApps.Metro. I am stuck at one situation here.
I would like to showcase ProgressRing when I click on Button. The Button click event should display ProgressRing and perform some code execution. Below is my code.
Here is my XML file code:
<Grid
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <Controls:ProgressRing
            Name="PrgRing" 
            Foreground="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"
            IsActive="False" />

       <Button Name="BtnShow"
            Style="{DynamicResource MahApps.Styles.Button.Square}"
            Content="Show Packages"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="10"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Width="100"
            Height="30"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>

Here is my PowerShell code:
$BtnShow.add_Click({
    $PrgRing.IsActive = $True
    .
    .
    # My code which will connect to server and fetch data and display into DataGrid
    .
    # After fetching all data ProgressRing should be stopped/completed. Hence, I have written below code.

    $PrgRing.IsActive = $False

})

When I click on Button, the ProgressRing is not appearing on screen.
Can someone suggest me what am I doing wrong here or what can be done to get this thing done? I already did google but got nothing relevant in PowerShell + WPF + MahApps.Metro
Note: I kept ProgressRing as active by default in XML file, just to check if is appearing or not. Answer is it is appearing by default.
Thank you for your help in advance.

Could you share a Minimal, Reproducible Example of your powershell code please?

@nalka Above code is fine the exact code I have.

Ok, let me take your snippet and run it as is to reproduce your problem... It doesn't reproduce it but yields a ParserError instead. See what I mean? I guess there should be at least a line like Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework, stuff that uses your XAML and to install MahApps.Metro

I think $PrgRing is not a directly accessable inside the event handler, you need to make it accessable by changing the scope like this or by binding it to a buttons property, like tag inside the view.
$BtnShow =     $Window.FindName("BtnShow")
    $PrgRing = $Window.FindName("PrgRing")
    
    # Create the event handler, capture the surrounding scope using GetNewClosure()
    $eventHandler = {
        # Start the ProgressRing by making it visible
        $PrgRing.Visibility = 'Visible'
        
        # Simulate connecting to a server and fetching data
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 3  # Simulate a long-running task
    
        # After fetching all data, stop the ProgressRing by hiding it
        $PrgRing.Visibility = 'Collapsed'
    }.GetNewClosure()
    
    # Assign the event handler to the button's click event
    $BtnShow.Add_Click($eventHandler)
    
    # Show the window
    $Window.ShowDialog()


This is not working. My ProgressRing is stuck when code gets executed.
